# Can i use Samsung Galaxy Sm-T210R as phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 SM-T210R purchased in US. In India it is marketed as Neo 3 with voice calling facility. Is it possible to modify SM-T210R as Neo 3 and use it for GSM sim based voice calling ability just like Neo 3.
Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Neo is not the same as the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 SM-T210R according to the Samsung website, and the Neo uses a sim (2G or 3G).

The SM-T210R is a WiFi device:

http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/SM-T210RGNYXAR-specs

The Neo is a GSM device:

http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/tablet-smartphone/SM-T111NYKAINU

(And the dimensions are different as well)

GSM Arena confirms the non-GSM, though I can't post the link because I have <10 rep.

Comment: GSMArena link:  http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_3_7_0_wifi-5423.php

Comment: Correct, it simply has no cellular hardware.